# Rails 5 ActionCable is crossing messages between development and production environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, production-environment, actioncable

I have my development server working at localhost:3000 and my production environment working ok at localhost:8001, both on the same machine.

When I trigger any cable event in the development server, it impact on production environment too.

Which is the best way to config ActionCable for support different environments and prevent cross messages?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

My cable.yml file was:

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://127.0.0.1:6379

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://127.0.0.1:6379
```

So I change it to

```
development:
  adapter: async

test:
  adapter: async

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://127.0.0.1:6379
```